# Decrease object size when stepped on by player in Lua

Tags: lua, roblox

I would like to know how to gradually increase the size of an object in Lua (every individual time a player steps on that object or an action is performed).
My code is as follows:

```
local snowPart = game.Workspace.Snow.SnowPart -- part I want to change
while snowPart.Size.Y == Vector3.new(0, 0, 0) do
    wait(10)
    snowPart.Size.Y = snowPart.Size + Vector3.new(0, 0.7, 0) --increment if the part gets too small
end

function onTouch(otherPart)
    local character = otherPart.Parent
    local humanoid = character:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Humanoid")
    if humanoid then
        wait(5)
        snowPart.Size = snowPart.Size.Y - Vector3.new(0, 0.7, 0) --increment the part's size when touched by a player
    end

end
snowPart.Touched:Connect(onTouch)
```

Comment: From what I can see, if `snowPart.Size.Y` is (0, 0, 0), you are currently forcing `snowPart.Size.Y` to be (0, 0.7, 0), and if a humanoid steps on the snowPart, you decrement the size by (0, 0.7, 0) based on this. However, the next iteration of the while loop will reset the size to (0, 0.7, 0). What is your intended behavior? [Note: I have no idea how Size and Size.Y work in this context or why Size.Y is a Vector3 rather than a simple double]

Answer (score 1):

Size.Y refers to a NumberValue, you are trying to compare and add with vectors.

```
local snowPart = game.Workspace.Snow.SnowPart -- part I want to change
while snowPart.Size.Y <= 0 do
    wait(10)
    snowPart.Size.Y = snowPart.Size + Vector3.new(0, 0.7, 0) --increment if the part gets too small
end

function onTouch(otherPart)
    local character = otherPart.Parent
    local humanoid = character:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Humanoid")
    if humanoid then
        wait(5)
        snowPart.Size = snowPart.Size - Vector3.new(0, 0.7, 0) --increment the part's size when touched by a player
    end

end
snowPart.Touched:Connect(onTouch)
```

You might want to look at using lerp and making the transition smoother.
Also it might be worth to look at the wiki for functions. http://wiki.roblox.com

Answer (score 0):

Like @Evan Wrynn's answer, yes, you're trying to set `Size.Y`, a read-only number value to a Vector3. I suggest `TweenService`.  ([Some documentation on creating tweens, with an example.](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/TweenService/Create))

So, here's a simple example:

```lua
local tweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")
local snowPart = game.Workspace.Snow.SnowPart -- part I want to change
while snowPart.Size == Vector3.new(snowPart.Size.X, 0, snowPart.Size.Z) do
    wait(10)
    snowPart.Size = snowPart.Size + Vector3.new(0, 0.7, 0) --increment if the part gets too small
end

function onTouch(otherPart)
    local character = otherPart.Parent
    local humanoid = character:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Humanoid")
    if humanoid then
        wait(5)
        local info = TweenInfo.new(.5) -- .5 seconds
        local tween = tweenService:Create(snowPart, info, {
            Size = snowPart.Size - Vector3.new(0, 0.7, 0)
        })
        tween:Play()
        -- If you don't want to wait for the tween, remove this.
        wait(.5)
    end

end
snowPart.Touched:Connect(onTouch)
```

That should smooth things out a bit.  Happy coding!